# Drawing ripple over view group content

Tags: android, rippledrawable

I'm trying to apply a ripple effect (`@drawable/pill`) to a layout. The ripple draws under the layout children, while I'd like the effect to be applied over the content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/pill"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/my_icon"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sample text"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And pill.xml (where `@drawable/pill_bg` is a custom shape):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask" android:drawable="@drawable/pill_bg"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pill_bg"/>
</ripple>
```

Following other posts, I tried applying `android:background="@null"` and `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` to the `ImageView` with no luck.

Does it even make sense to have the ripple defined as the background of a layout? I'm wondering if the right approach is to separate the ripple from the background drawable, and apply the ripple to a dummy view that overlaps the content.

Comment: Did you get your desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You are right. What you have defined in the xml, works like as shown in the first diagram. To have the ripple drawable above the ImageView and TextView, you need to define it above them. One approach to achieve that would be to have an ImageView on top of your LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/my_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sample text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_ripple"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ll_container"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/ll_container"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/ll_container"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/ll_container"
        android:src="@drawable/pill" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up keeping the ripple under the textview & imageview as I didn't find the suggested approach clean.